Voltage drops when trying to get high current from boost converter
I have designed a Boost converter which boost 5V input to 12V output. I designed it using TPS61378 boost converter IC by Texas instruments. I was able to get around 450mA current from the output without any voltage drop. But when I reduce the load resistor to 22ohm, It only gave 490mA and voltage dropped to 10.9V. (It should give around 540mA with 12V output). So what could be the reason for that? I attached a snapshot of my design below.

Thanks in advance!

Is the 5 V source still providing 5 V when the boost converter output drops?

Yes, I supplied power from a bench power supply. It shows constant 5V without any drop and i didn't add any current limit from input side.

Check the inductor datasheet for saturation current

I checked it, it is mentioned as 6.3A. (part number - FNR6045S2R7NT).

Post an image of your PCB.

\$I_{LIM}\$ is set to a quite low value according to my calculations: -

Image from the data sheet.
Your R6 sets the limit. It is 61.9 kΩ and that means the current limit is 1.49 amps. If you can get 450 mA on the output without problem, the average current on the input side will be at least 12/5 times higher at 1.08 amps but, the peak current could be up to twice this value in DCM and that would trigger the current limit hence, you are likely operating in CCM.
Having said that, the peak current in CCM could be quite close to the limiting current you have set so, I think that you haven't got enough margin to suit your requirements.
Of course, there may be other problems but this one sticks out a tad.

Is this resistor set the input side current limit, i thought it limits output side current and put a 61.9kohm resistor to limit output current around 1.5A. Seems like i have misunderstood that equation in datasheet.

@KSHewa look at section 8.2 in the data sheet. Current limiting is on the low-side MOSFET and it is monitoring the charging current into the inductor. Internally ILIM gets named CLIM and, that directly controls maximum inductor charge current (which is also the peak current delivered to the output when transferring energy). If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Got it.Appreciate your help! I will check and let you know.
